# Is it possible to infect a wired headset with any kind of malware?

Tags: malware, audio

I got a HyperX Cloud Stinger headset, wired and 3.5mm connector.
Is it possible to infect my headset with some kind of malware?

If my headset is infected with any kind of malware, it would transfer some malware to another computer that I plug my headset in. That worries me.

If I plug my headset in some computer and that computer infects my headset with some malware. That worries me too.

I don't know if it is possible through any way or if a wired 3.5mm headset has some kind of embedded system.

Comment: Does the audio jack transfer data or just sound signals?

Comment: I read online that some miniaturized electronic devices use 2.5 mm or 3.5 mm jacks as serial port connectors for data transfer. So in my case I'm not sure.

Comment: Sure, but that's just a connector to a serial port. Your audio port is not a serial data port.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!
You all helped me to solve the case.